# Writing grant applications as a new academic/faculty member

Tags: research-process, funding, academic-life, independent-researcher, productivity

I am a new faculty member at a University. In the last 5 months since I started, I have applied (or in process of applying) 4 research grants (2 internal applied, 2 external in the process).

What I have found difficult is that for the current two external grants, I feel I need to do a lot of research myself, learn new topics, techniques, and/or algorithms. The call-for-grants do not exactly match my existing research expertise, though the domains are the same.

My question is about spending a lot of time researching to learn new techniques/tools/algorithms to be able to apply for a grant. Is it normal, or is my approach wrong and I should not apply for those grants? I am feeling a bit lost. It seems challenging to decide if it is wise for me to spend my time writing grants for calls not exactly matching my area.

Researching for my applications and writing them does not leave enough time for me to do my own publishable research (in a publish-or-perish culture) as I have to do teaching as well as other non-teaching services at university.

Comment: Which country are you in (or, at least, which continent are you on)? The European grant application process is rather different from the USA one, say. Regardless of anything, 4 grant applications in 5 months seems quite an overkill to me: you have time neither to prepare your applications properly (the main issue is the proposal itself; you'd better know what exactly you want to say there and that requires some thinking of the subject; and a badly composed proposal means an almost certain rejection), nor to do anything else. I would certainly slow that crazy pace down at least twice.

Comment: I am in China. I am an international faculty and hence I have limited options which support English language funding. Hence, this is another reason I want to apply.

Comment: You need to discuss this with the chair, or whoever is responsible for judging your performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mentor told me, "If you aren't getting rejections on your grants, you aren't submitting enough applications."  That is true, with some caveats.  I think you ultimately need to be focused on a particular area.  You can move toward the boundaries of your area -- but, be careful about "chasing" money.  To develop as a scholar, you should think about creating a coherent portfolio of research.  When you look at grant opportunities, consider the likelihood of getting funded and whether that is an area you are really willing to invest your time.

The other thing my mentor taught me:  "Work to live. Don't live to work."  Keep that one in your back pocket.

Comment: I disagree with both statements. The first one, IMHO, should be "If you don't get awards, you should apply smarter, not wider" and the second should be "Find a work that can be a part of your meaning of life". But I'm an old-fashioned reptile in this brave new world :-).